# UBUNTU 14.04 HDMI overscan Issue

Tags: nvidia, xorg, hdmi, display-resolution

I am using an HTPC using HDMI connected to a TV screen via a Denon AVAmp.
The graphic card is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 TI.
With a fresh install of UBUNTU 14.04, I noticed an overscan.
I installed Nvidia driver and with Nvidia-settings, I managed to have the proper display with the parameters : Resolution 1920x1080@60hz and underscan value 43.
This is saved to xorg.conf.

However, after reboot, the underscan value is kept but the resolution and frequency are displayed as "auto" in the Nvidia-settings and are in fact 1920x1080@50hz.

How to keep the refreshing rate at 60hz?

I have also read the EDID which indicates that 1920x1080@50hz is the preferred mode but 1920x1080@60hz is also supported.

60hz is also the default refreshing rate between the AVamp and the TV.

Any clue welcome.